# C Auto variables

Tags: c

Variables declared as auto variables are local to the blocks in which they are defined in C.
Consider the code below,

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    char *fun();
    int main()
    {   
      char *s;
      s= fun();
      printf("%s\n", s);
      return 0;
    }
    char *fun()
    {
       char buffer[30];
       strcpy(buffer, "RAM");
       return (buffer);
     }
```

This is a code I found on net (it was a MCQ question). The output is unpredictable and so throws error since buffer is an auto array and will die when the control go back to main. Thus s will be pointing to an array , which not exists.

Now consider this code.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int sum(int x,int y)
    {   
      int c=x+y;
      return c;
    }

    int main()
    {
      int a=1,b=2;
      int c=sum(a,b);
      printf("%d",c);
    }
```

In this code, the variable c is also an auto variable declared inside the function sum which means it is local to that function and cannot be accessed outside the function. But how does this code compile successfully without throwing any error. Why?

Comment: You're copying the value of `c`, not returning a pointer to the variable.

Comment: The problem would be if you wrote `return &c;`

Comment: Remember that arrays are converted to a pointer when used as an r-value.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that in the first example you're returning a pointer with the address to a variable. This pointer is not valid after the variable goes out of scope. In your second example, you're just copying the value of the variable.

This works:

```
int sum(int x,int y) {   
  int c=x+y;
  return c;
}
```

But not this

```
int *sum(int x,int y) {   
  int c=x+y;
  return &c;
}
```

However, this does, because it's not an auto variable:

```
int *sum(int x,int y) {   
  static int c=x+y;
  return &c;
}
```